# WCF rest service to accept dynamic as parameter

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, dynamic

In my application, I am sending a json object to a service and at the service end, I expect an object of type dynamic

```
public bool TestService(dynamic entity)
{
    // process
}
```

When i debug and see the entity filled, I am not able to type cast it. Any idea how i can retrieve fields from the entity sent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm curious - if you're sending up a JSON formatted object, why not have your service method accept a string and then use something like JSON.net to cast it to the appropriate type?

```
public bool TestService(string entity)
{
    var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObjectType>(entity);
    //do stuff with myObject...
}
```

Or you could deserialize it into an anonymous object:

```
public bool TestService(string entity)
{
    var myAnonymousObject = new { Name = String.Empty, Address = String.Empty };
    var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(entity, myAnonymousObject);
    //do stuff with myObject
}
```

I guess I'm not sure why your JSON formatted object needs to be dynamic.